# Как перевести COM порт в режим PDU Java

Tags: java, jssc

у меня есть модем quectel m35 который подключен к COM порту.
Я пытаюсь получить с него данные, для взаимодействия с ним взята библиотека jssc, вычитал что нужно чтобы отправлять ему команды, перевести модем в режим PDU, команда для перевода AT+CMGF=1, но у меня почему то он ее не принимает, подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так.

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortEvent;
import jssc.SerialPortEventListener;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

public class NewModem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM243");
        try {
            port.openPort();
            System.out.println("Открываем порт" + port);
            port.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_115200,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            System.out.println("Задаем параметры" + port);
           
            port.writeString("AT+CMGF=1");
            System.out.println("Переводим в режим PDU" + port);
           
            port.writeString("AT+CPMS=\"MT\"");

            String s =  port.readString();
            System.out.println("читаем" + s);

        } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


Результат выполнения
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Открываем портjssc.SerialPort@246b179d
Задаем параметрыjssc.SerialPort@246b179d
Переводим в режим PDUjssc.SerialPort@246b179d
читаемAT+CMGF=1AT+CPMS="MT"

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Буду признателен за любую помощь, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+CMGF это выбор кодека для текстов смс

+CPMS это выбор где хранить входящие смс

но команды не принялись потому что нет перевода строки "\r\n" в конце команды.

Comment: Да все верно, спасибо Вам добавил "\r\n" и все заработало

Comment: можно галочку поставить